# Using plot and scatter on same figure with different colors but even if I plot first, the scatter still show up UNDER the plot

Tags: python, plot, scatter

I am plotting a distribution of variables that are outputs from two different versions of a program. They look very similar (this is great because they should!) and I am showing their ratio in the same figure but on a different axis. My goal is to show the ratio as a scatter plot but with a horizontal line at y=1.0 to show 100% agreement. The issue I am having is even if I plot the line first and then the scatter, my scatter points still show underneath the line plot. (Please see the image linked below.) **You can see the scatter in black underneath the line plot in red, even though I call the plot function first.** Any recommendations? Thank you!

[Distribution of two variables with ratio plot underneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NOS5.png)

Comment: This is what the two lines of code look like: `ax.plot([-10.0, 700.0],[1.0,1.0],'-',color='red')
ax.scatter(x, eff_hist, marker='_', color='black')`

Comment: Essentially it seems like the colors from plot and scatter are interfering with each other. I tried with line color = gainsboro and scatter color = black and the scatter plot shows up as darkish grey. What is happening?